# How to scroll a JLayeredpane in java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a java class that contains one layeredpane with 2 JPanel and a scroller.

There are 2 drawings so that I'll be able to draw different things with different threads on each panel, however, nothing happens when I use this class, and, I've checked if I delete the layeredPane and drawingPane0, creating the scroller with drawingPane1, it works correctly...

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thank you all!

Here it's my code:

public class ScrollPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

```
private Dimension area; //indicates area taken up by graphics
private Vector<Rectangle> circles; //coordinates used to draw graphics
private JPanel drawingPane0;
private JPanel drawingPane1;
private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

private final Color colors[] = {
    Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.orange,
    Color.cyan, Color.magenta, Color.darkGray, Color.yellow};
private final int color_n = colors.length;

public ScrollPanel() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    area = new Dimension(0, 0);
    circles = new Vector<Rectangle>();
    drawingPane1 = new DrawingPane();
    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    drawingPane0 = new DrawingPane();
    drawingPane0.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    drawingPane1.addMouseListener(this);
    drawingPane1.setOpaque(false);
    layeredPane.add(drawingPane0,0);
    layeredPane.add(drawingPane1,1);

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(layeredPane);
    add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


public class DrawingPane extends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Rectangle rect;
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
            rect = circles.elementAt(i);
            g.setColor(colors[(i % color_n)]);
            g.fillOval(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        }
    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    final int W = 100;
    final int H = 100;
    boolean changed = false;
    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
        circles.removeAllElements();
        area.width = 0;
        area.height = 0;
        changed = true;
    } else {
        int x = e.getX() - W / 2;
        int y = e.getY() - H / 2;
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        }
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, W, H);
        circles.addElement(rect);
        drawingPane1.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
        int this_width = (x + W + 2);
        if (this_width > area.width) {
            area.width = this_width;
            changed = true;
        }
        int this_height = (y + H + 2);
        if (this_height > area.height) {
            area.height = this_height;
            changed = true;
        }
    }
    if (changed) {
        drawingPane1.setPreferredSize(area);
        drawingPane1.revalidate();
    }
    drawingPane1.repaint();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

}

Comment: By dfault, the JLayeredPane has no LayoutManager, this means that you must now take control of this functionality (or supply one). Since there is no layout manager, the default size of the JLayeredPane and drawing panels is 0x0. Assuming that you want panel1 over panel2, you could use a OverlayLayout manager (instead of the JLayerdPane) or maybe a GridBagLayout of you configure it correctly...

Comment: *"draw different things with different threads on each panel*" - Remember, Swing is not thread safe and you should only update the UI from within the context of the EDT

Comment: Okay then, thanks MadProgrammer, I'll give a try with OverlayLayout manager. Thanks for answering!